# Making code documentation an automated requirement for a commit (or build).

Tags: git, build, gruntjs, web-deployment, jsdoc

I'm about to start on a large-scale .js project and as part of the workflow process, I'd like to enforce code documentation. I'm leaning towards JSDoc (2.x).

Ideally, I'd like to intercept non-documented code. I'm interested in anything that will either:

- Stop a build on the developer's machine using Grunt, Gulp or similar.
- Use a git hook to prevent non-documented code from getting pushed to the repo.
- Run a server-side pre deployment check and fail a build.

Answer (score 1):

Git can run scripts on the client to make some checks before code is committed or pushed.

I'm not aware of any scripts that you can actually run on the server; the Git server is not very sophisticated since you can always undo any changes.

Also making documentation a requirement doesn't sound like a strategy to me. Usually documentation is necessary to document bugs and flaws in the design and code (i.e. people can't understand or use the product *without* it - if the flaws were not there, there was no need to explain how to use it).

From my experience, you will fare better by doing code reviews to make sure the quality stays high.

Comment: +1 for doing code reviews before stuff gets merged into the main branch. I commit regularly with temp code / my current state and at the end do a refactoring/clean up confusing parts and stuff like that. Enforcing this for each commit or even before running tests is a bad idea IMHO. For git-commit-hooks, there is also `--no-verify` which ignores hooks, so that doesn't always help.

Comment: I should specify that the requirement should be enforced on specific builds. Building and deploying to sandboxed and dev environments is fine. The goal is to enforce for anything higher environments (Stage, QA, Prod).

Comment: My first thought while reading this was "So documentation is an afterthought?" Also, do you really want to enforce documentation for even the most simple code (like accessor methods in Java)? If someone told me to implement this in my company, I'd quit. If someone asked me to implement it, I'd say it would take 4-5 years to train an AI so it won't ask for useless documentation. You may also want to read this: http://blog.pdark.de/2012/10/11/tnbt-documentation-sucks/

Comment: One more thing: forcing people to add comments to the code will not give you good documentation. They can get away with sprinkling the code with `/* xxx */` to pass the test. You want them to give an overview (but there is no good place in the code to put this) or *why* someone wants to use a certain method. Everything else is mostly a waste of time.

Comment: The project is an API that will be consumed by 3rd party. Code documentation is a business requirement.

Comment: Are we talking about API docs or comments inside of methods?